# Accidentally used homebrew to change my default python to 3.7, how do I change it back to 2.7?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, homebrew

I was trying to install python 3 because I wanted to work on a project using python 3. Instructions I'd found were not working, so I boldly ran `brew install python`. Wrong move. Now when I run `python -V` I get "Python 3.7.3", and when I try to enter a virtualenv I get `-bash: /Users/elliot/Library/Python/2.7/bin/virtualenv: /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`

My `~/.bash_profile` reads 
`export PATH="/Users/elliot/Library/Python/2.7/bin:/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:/Library/PostgreSQL/10/bin:$PATH"`

but `ls /usr/local/Cellar/python/` gets me `3.7.3` so it seems like brew doesn't even know about my old 2.7 version anymore.

I think what I want is to reset my system python to 2.7, and then add python 3 as a separate python running on my system. I've been googling, but haven't found any advice on how to specifically use brew to do this.

Edit: I'd also be happy with keeping Python 3.7, if I knew how to make virtualenv work again. I remember hearing that upgrading your system python breaks everything, but I'd be super happy to know if that's outdated knowledge and I'm just being a luddite hanging on to 2.7.

Comment: Looks like hombrew is trying to do you a favor... ;)

Comment: Yes, I know, what am I doing still on 2.7? The answer is trying to not deal with upgrading right this moment. If it's simpler to update my path so virtualenv knows how to run again, I'd be happy with that solution too.

Answer (score 0):

So, I got through it by completely uninstalling Python, which I'd been reluctant to do, and then reinstalled Python 2. I had to update my path and open a new shell to get it to see the new python 2 installation, and things fell into place. I'm now using pyenv for my Python 3 project, and it's a dream.